# Having errors with Java assignment

Tags: java

I'm getting some errors in code I wrote for an assignment, and I can't quite understand them.

```
I:\Java Programming\FibonacciJDialog.java:19: error: variable sum might not have been initialized
        return sum;
               ^
I:\Java Programming\FibonacciJDialog.java:20: error: unreachable statement
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That Fibonacci Number is" ); // Display results in dialog box.
        ^
I:\Java Programming\FibonacciJDialog.java:25: error: missing return statement
    }
    ^
3 errors
Tool completed with exit code 1
```

Here is the code:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class FibonacciJDialog {

    public static long main(String[] args) {
        String num;
        int n;
        int sum;

        num = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter n: "); // getting user number input.
        n = Integer.parseInt(num);

        Fibonacci box = new Fibonacci(); // Creating new Fibonacci object.

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "That Fibonacci Number is"); // Display results in dialog box.
        return sum;

        System.exit(0); // Terminate

    }
}
```

This is the Fibonacci class I made.

```
public class Fibonacci {
    int Fib(int n) {
        int in1 = 1, in2 = 1;
        int sum = 0;//initial value
        int index = 1;
        while (index < n) {
            // sum=the sum of 2 values;
            // in1 gets in2
            // in2 gets sum
            // increment index
        }
        return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sum` never gets anything put in it. And why are you returning it from `main`? Did you mean to add it to the end of the string to put it in the dialog?

Comment: Fibonacci is pure recursion. You could refer to done [sample code](http://java67.blogspot.sg/2012/07/java-program-fibonacci-series-with.html?m=1)  first.

Comment: @bonCodigo: It's pretty easy to compute iteratively, exactly as described in the question.

Comment: @minitech can see that after your comment to OP. :-)  I am just too engrossed with recursion flavour of it and used the typical code always.  e.g. ` fibonacci(number - 1) + fibonacci(number - 2);` but it is good to see new ways of doing things.

Answer (score 2):

You never assign a value to sum.

```
sum = box.fib(n);
```

In your main function, you also return the value instead of outputting it to the console.

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"That Fibonacci Number is" + sum);
```

Comment: I cant change the fibonacci.java file at all and when I make the change to sum = box.fib(n); i get three errors.

Comment: Why can you not change it? The one posted has no code to actually create the fib number. And what errors are thrown, it helps to provide details when things go wring o you can get better support from the community.

Answer (score 0):

A few errors I've noticed:

1. You don't assign `sum` a value.  It's only declared, but not initialized.  That's what the stack trace tells you - you have to initialize the value to something.
2. I'm willing to bet that the "unreachable code" is a red herring - after you initialize your variable I don't see any code path that won't take you to `new`ing your Fibonacci class.
3. For some reason, you've decided to return `long` from `main()`.  I'm not sure how that's working  - you may have some other `main` method somewhere else that calls this class - but you can either return a `long`, or set the signature of the method to `void`.